# How to determine data's constructor from foreign code?

Tags: haskell, ffi

In my Haskell program i have an ADT with many constructors:

```
data MyData = Con1 |
    Con2 |
    ...
    Con20
```

I have an `foreign export ccall` function, which wraps `[MyData]` into array of `StablePtr's`. After calling it i need to determine which constructor have been used to construct each element.

It could be solved this way

```
foreign export ccall getType :: StablePtr MyData -> IO CInt
getType (Con1) = return 1
getType (Con2) = return 2
...
```

but then i would need to manually define these constants in C header. This is error-prone, so i wonder if there is a way to make GHC do this job for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for this.

I've defined possible constructor types as enum in my C code:

```
typedef enum
{
    MyDataCon1,
    MyDataCon2,
    ...
    MyDataCon20
} MyDataConstructor;
```

Then i used [C->Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hs) enum hook in my Haskell source:

```
{#enum MyDataConstructor deriving (Show) #}
```

After preprocessing this line turns to

```
data MyDataConstructor = MyDataCon1
    | MyDataCon2
    ...
    | MyDataCon20
```

Now i can define `getType` this way:

```
foreign export ccall getType :: StablePtr MyData -> IO CInt
getType md = do
    md' <- deRefStablePtr md
    case md' of
        Con1 -> return $ fromEnum MyDataCon1
        Con2 -> return $ fromEnum MyDataCon2
        ...
        Con20 -> return $ fromEnum MyDataCon20
```

Answer (score 6):

deriving `Enum` for your Haskell type, and export `fromEnumMyData :: MyData -> Int ; fromEnumMyData = fromEnum`.

Then you can do case analysis on the C side by looking at the Int tag GHC assigns.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. How do i know to which constructor refers some tag?

Comment: You don't - it is given by the enumeration ordering. But you've already lost all that information on the C side anyway, so you have to rely on an unsafe mapping.

Comment: So, it's not possible to automatically generate that mapping?

Comment: What mapping are you trying to generate? GHC already generates a mapping from Int to 'a', and 'a' to Int. But on the C side you can't use 'a's.

Comment: I want GHC to put something like `#define CON1_ID 1`, `#define CON2_ID 2`, ... into generated header.